# What to call the attitude of pursuing something

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What will you call a person with an endless spirit of pursuing something?

Comment: **Predatorial** sometimes fits this sort of behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Determined/resolute person:

[Determination](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Determination), resolution:

> - Firmness of purpose; resolve: approached the task with determination and energy.
> - A fixed intention or resolution: returned to school with a determination to finish.

also [unyielding](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unyielding) or tenacious :

> - Not bending; inflexible
> - Not giving way to pressure or persuasion; obdurate.

Source: www.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: can I write one of the most beautiful thing which I loved the most is `endless spirit of pursuing goals `

Comment: I basically want to quote team

Comment: @Pilot- One of the things I loved most about the team was its endless enthusiasm for pursuing goals.

Comment: +1 for tenacious: Merriam-Webster, 1. continuing for a long time 2. very determined to do something

Answer (score 7):

The word Doggedness comes to my mind.

In some situations single-mindedly would also be useful.

Answer (score 3):

*Undeflectable*, *undeterrable* and *indefatigable* use litotes.

*Unswerving* perhaps does too.

*Compelled* or *compulsive* relate to monomania, an unhealthy drivenness.

Answer (score 3):

Adjectives describe a noun.

More positive connotation:
**impassioned, fervent, wholehearted, unwavering, steadfast, pledged, dedicated, driven**

Less positive connotation:
**preoccupied, haunted, obsessed, plagued, consumed, tormented**

Simile might help:

"He was not unlike Pacman in his constant quest for junk food."

Answer (score 2):

What came to mind when reading the question was **relentless**.

**re·lent·less**
/rəˈlen(t)ləs/

- oppressively constant; incessant.
- that does not relent; unyieldingly severe, strict, or harsh; unrelenting:

"His relentless pursuit of perfection was his undoing."

Comment: Many of these words convey "endless", but the requested  pursuit aspect is missing.

Answer (score 1):

**"Grit"** is a great word for this personal trait.

A person with grit has perseverance, zeal, resilience, and determination.
Source: [Grit (personality trait) on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grit_%28personality_trait%29)

Answer (score 0):

If it was a case of continuing when the odds of success are diminishing, but you didn't want a word with connotations of mental illness or stubbornness, I'd go with **persevering**.

Answer (score 0):

*Volition* perhaps fits according to some sources.

Answer (score 0):

**Ambitious**, [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambitious),  adjective, 1. having ambition; eagerly desirous of achieving or obtaining success, power, wealth, a specific goal, etc.

It's quite *ambitious* to pursue something with endless spirit.

Answer (score 0):

How about **perseverance**: \ˌpər-sə-ˈvir-ən(t)s\

> - The quality that allows someone to continue trying to do something even though it is difficult.
> - Continued effort to do or achieve something despite difficulties, failure, or opposition.

Source: [Perseverance. Merriam-Webster.com.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perseverance)